# Finding the biggest number with ForkJoin

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

Without block `if delay == 2` it works, but doesn't work with it.

Here's ForkJoin's compute:

```
compute() {

    if(lastElem - firstElem == 1)
        return array[firstElem];

    if(lastElem - firstElem == 2){

        if(array[firstElem] > array[lastElem])
            return array[firstElem];
        else
            return array[lastElem];
    }

    int midElem = (firstElem + lastElem) / 2;

    MyForkJoinTask left = new MyForkJoinTask(array, firstElem, midElem);
    MyForkJoinTask right = new MyForkJoinTask(array, midElem, lastElem);

    left.fork();
    right.fork();

    int leftResult = left.join();
    int rightResult = right.join();

    if(leftResult > rightResult)
        return leftResult;
    else
        return rightResult;


}
```

Here's my main method:

```
main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    MyForkJoinTask root = new MyForkJoinTask(array);
    F_J_POOL.submit(root);
    System.out.println("Result is " + root.join());
}
```

Short error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>
> at com.bg.fork_join.MainFJ.main(MainFJ.java:24)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>     ... 15 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10000
>     at com.bg.fork_join.MyForkJoinTask.compute(MyForkJoinTask.java:31)

Could you show me where the problem is?

Comment: line 31? MyForkJoinTask.java

Comment: I changed formatting of your code, added the missing return-type declarations and field-declarations. Also on StackOverflow you normally don't change the title to "... can be closed" - you can archive closing of a question by flagging it ("flag" is just underneath the tags); questions are primarily being closed, because there is SPAM or other inappropriate content. This is so that maybe even better answers can be added. So happy coding your problem was solved :)

Comment: @TheConstructor you shouldn't close spam. You should flag it for deletion.

Comment: @JanDvorak you are right. Still it's both starting with a flag ;-) Was trying to keep the comment from exploding.

Comment: @TheConstructor - Questions should only be closed when they are inappropriate for the site (off topic, poorly described, etc.), not when the asker gets an answer. Please don't suggest people flag this, as we will decline these flags.

Comment: @BradLarson I did not suggest to flag this for closure. I was just trying to explain what you just said and why you even then would not edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `ForkJoin`, but this looks suspicious just on general principles:

```
if(lastElem - firstElem == 2){

    if(array[firstElem] > array[lastElem])
        return array[firstElem];
    else
        return array[lastElem];
}
```

The rest of your code makes it appear that you're processing a subarray from `firstElem` (inclusive) to `lastElem` (**exclusive**), so shouldn't you be using `lastElem-1` to index?